# How to disprove an equality involving a double integral

Tags: real-analysis, integration, probability-distributions, integral-transforms, oscillatory-integral

I want to show that the following equality does not hold:

\begin{equation}\label{at3}
    \frac{\lambda^2-1}{2}x^2-\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\!\!\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}K(y_1,y_2,x)\ln g(y_1,y_2)dy_2dy_1=\mbox{constant}\ \ ,\ \ \forall x\in\mathbb{R},
\end{equation}
where $\lambda>1$, and
\begin{equation}\label{at2}
    g(y_1,y_2)=\int_{-1}^{1}e^{-\frac{(\lambda^2-1)u^2}{2}+\lambda y_1u}\cosh\left(y_2\sqrt{1-u^2}\right)dF(u),
\end{equation}
in which $F(u)$ is an unknown cumulative distribution function (CDF) for $U$ with the support $[-1,1]$. It could be discrete or continuous or a mixture. Finally,
\begin{align}
    K(y_1,y_2,x)=e^{-\frac{(\lambda^2-1)}{2}x^2}e^{\frac{-y_1^2-y_2^2+2\lambda y_1x}{2}}\cos \left(y_2\sqrt{x^2-1}\right).
\end{align}
In order to show that the first equality is not valid, I tried to see the scaling behaviour of the double integral term in $x$. I think that the double integral term is at most $O(x)$, so that it cannot cancel the effect of the first term $\frac{\lambda^2-1}{2}x^2$. However, I was not successful.

I highly appreciate your help about this problem.